# Best ways to find out the reasons behind Spring Boot application is slowing down in Production environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, production-environment

We are running multiple Spring Boot applications on Production servers. In recent time, we observed **slowness in production** to that workflow where Spring Boot applications are running.

We are using **Spring Actuator** to check health and processes but didn't find any solution.

We also have **thread dumps** backups with us for debugging.

Comment: Slowness in the sense the response from API right..??

Comment: Maybe JProfile would help?